# AP div position differs slightly in chrome, firefox, safari

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, css-position

I'm trying to AP a div in the header of my blog containing a bg image and a link. I looks correct in Chrome, but incorrect in Safari and Firefox. I suspect it's not the AP div itself but other elements causing the shift, though I can't figure out what, and I'm using a reset.

Here's a link to screenshots show you what I'm talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxtSo.jpg

Here's a link to the website:

http://www.artyst-tyrant.com/blog

Here's the css I'm using:

```
#trex-blog {
margin-left: 435px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
z-index: 50000;
```

}

```
#trex-blog a, #trex-blog a:visited, #trex-blog a:hover {
background: url(../img/blog-trex.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
display: block;
height: 121px;
width: 356px;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
overflow: hidden;    
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="trex-blog"><a href="http://www.artyst-tyrant.com" title="Artyst Tyrant - Victor Beazzo Designer for Hire">Artyst Tyrant - Victor Beazzo Designer for Hire</a></div>
```

Designer by trade who's trying his hand at learning to code, but I'm by no means a pro, so please, go easy.

Thank you in advance for your help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome v18 on Win7 renders the image in the same place as my other browsers - perhaps you were browsing a cached version on chrome only?

The only caveat to absolute positioning elements is if they are wrapped in a relatively positioned element - then the absolute position is relative to the parent - http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

I looked at your source code and didn't notice any position relative attributes on the parent elements.

I adjusted the css top attribute value to 20px and it aligned for me in all current browsers.

Comment: That fixes it for me in all other browsers, but it still looks off in chrome for me.  I already tried clearing my cache. There does appear to be more space in the header in chrome, not sure why.

Comment: Weird, I'd try disabling all extensions.  Then I'd use the dom inspector and specifically the Metrics panel to figure out what's causing that extra top margin.